# Create many to many from single table performance issue

Tags: mysql, performance, search, insert, procedure

I'm working with a rather large database (500+ millions entries), and am trying to optimize the search engine.

My main table is the following:

**items**
(id, mixed, value)

mixed contains the keywords related to this item (ex: "Jason Bourne is cool"). What I am trying to do, is to populate two new tables:

**item_terms**
(id, term)

**item_term_results**
(id, item_terms_id, items_id)

from the main table items. I have written a MySQL procedure looping through all the results from this main table, following this algorithm:

- Split items.mixed

  - Loop through the values we get:

    - Insert the value in item_terms
    - Insert a new result in item_term_results putting items.id into item_term_results.items_id and last_inserted_id() in item_term_results

The problem is, the procedure takes *way* too much time to process. With that much data, the procedure would need 150 days to complete, which is way too much even if we're on a very powerful server.

Any idea of how to do this? We're basically doing this to make searches a lot faster than a simple like, as the values in item_terms.item will be unique.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have done the research to determine that your number of distinct terms (e.g. "Jason", "Bourne", "cool" is reasonably limited in size, even though you have a large items table.

Presumably you have also determined that MySQL's FULLTEXT search capability is not suitable for your application. If you have not investigated FULLTEXT search, I strongly suggest you do so. It may be the perfect thing.

Your item_term_results table does not need, and should not have, a separate `id` column. Make the primary key a composite of the two other columns, and put them into the key in the order `(item_terms_id, itemid)`

I suggest you figure out how to handle your bulk indexing offline, that is, disconnected from the data base. Here's my suggestion:

1. dump a simple, but big, text file where each line contains `id` then a tab then `mixed`
2. write a program that does the following.

   1. read each line of the table.
   2. split the line into individual items
   3. insert each item into an in-memory hash map, deduplicating it and giving it a unique `item_terms_id`, in memory, not in the database.
   4. for each item, write out a line to a text file `item_id` then tab then `item_terms_id`.
3. When you have processed all the lines in the input file, write out, to another text file, each term, in the form `item_terms_id` then tab then the text of the `term`.
4. Finally, use LOAD DATA INFILE to bulk-import these two files into MySQL.

This should take away the crippling overhead of doing row-by-row insertions. For half a gigarecord it will use a lot of RAM for the in-memory `item_terms` hash, and it may run for many hours, but not many days.

Again, though, before you bite this big bullet investigate FULLTEXT.  It's built to do what you seem to be doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I wasn't using FULLTEXT as we were using TokuDB, so I thought about this many-to-many relation may work pretty good. However, I don't understand why it is important that the number of keywords remains low? As item_terms.term will have a unique index, it should still be pretty much instant to search for it right? (I am converting the database to InnoDB and adding the fulltext index to test it though)

Comment: The idea is to deduplicate the keywords, so a search will find one entry in your `item_terms` table, then quickly look up the items in your `item_term_results` table.  Also, my strategy for ETL requires the keywords to fit in RAM, so there can't be billions of distinct ones.

Comment: After a few days of testing, FULLTEXT was indeed a good solution to this problem. However, I couldn't get it to work with InnoDB, the index generation was always failing and I had to switch to MyISAM to generate it (I guess there was too many entries). However, as I didn't like MyISAM, I switched to SphinxSearch which makes be able to use TokuDB as well as having better performances than FULLTEXT indexing.